# Como posso acessar dados ja modificados da tabela?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou desenvolvendo um software para uma empresa de Home Care. O software esta sendo criado exclusivamente para uma determinada cliente então ele funciona de acordo com a cabeça dela. Não estranhem o funcionamento.

Essa empresa tem seu pacientes, que pagam um valor fixo mensal. Muitas vezes o paciente dispensa os serviços por um período e depois volta. Preciso fazer algo muito simples que é subtrair do valor de mensalidade de cada cliente os custos que a empresa teve com ele em determinado mês e assim chegar ao lucro líquido.

Até aí tudo bem, eu sei fazer.

Porém eu também tenho que somar o lucro líquido que todos os pacientes geraram e assim saber o lucro liquido total do mês.

Não da para fazer `@paciente.lucro_liquido = @paciente.valor_do_contrato - @paciente.custo_1 - @paciente.custo_2` porque no mês seguinte o valor de contrato e dos custos muda e isso alteraria os valores dos meses anteriores.

Qual a melhor forma de resolver isso? Como posso separar as informações mês a mês?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, bom, e se você separar, colocar em tabelas diferentes. Todo mês, você chama um novo registro daquele paciente. Pelo que eu vejo é uma associação de 1 para n.

http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-relacionamentos-no-ruby-on-rails/33860

Dá uma lida. Talvez ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma seria ter um modelo para registrar os pagamentos dos clientes.
Depois fazer uma custom query. Dai na SQL query você faz e soma o total dos valores com um where passando o mês.